# Is it possible to connect to a remote MySQL database through an adobe air iOS app.

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, air, adobe

I've done some research and I know that you can connect using a server side language within adobe flex but would this be possible to do inside an iOS application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an ODBC driver for iOS:

http://www.prlog.org/10938886-open-database-connectivity-odbc-arrives-for-apple-ipad-iphone-and-ipod-touch.html

And apparently "C Driver for MySQL (Connector/C)" also works on iOS:

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

See this post about the C connector:

http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=20

Comment: This is correct but there is no database connector directly integrated into flex mobile so you need to create a solution to send data through a format like json or xml to your mobile application.

Comment: @user1809913 I guess I misread your question to be: "adobe flex works, what else works for iOS" not: "what works for adobe flex on iOS".  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement webservice. Webservice is an intermediater between flex and Mysql, Sqlserver any database